# Working with Math class without instantiating it

Tags: java, oop

I am new to  programming and was studying "Head First Java",  I just saw  a problem where there was used `Math` class like this

```
int x= Math.round(float value);
```

and it was mentioned we don't need  to instantiate Math class because its constructor is set `private`. What does that mean? Until now  I read we need to instantiate that class and reference variable to play around with methods and instance variables of the class how does Math class work like this?

Comment: Let the karma vulture feast begin...

Comment: In your book, read the chapter describing static methods.

Comment: @AlexWien sure i will

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use methods of a class without instantiating this class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394205/can-i-use-methods-of-a-class-without-instantiating-this-class)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> we don't need to instantiate Math class because its Constructor is set Private

Because all the methods in `Math` class are `static` you can use the class name to invoke them. So there is no use instantiating the class , hence the constructor was declared `private`. it will also prevent sub classing the `Math` class, since it is the **only** constructor.

Look at the [open source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Math.java#Math.%3Cinit%3E%28%29) :

> Don't let anyone instantiate this class.

```
 private Math() {} // only constructor defined in Math class
```

The methods of `Math` class doesn't depend on the internal state of the class , they are just like utility functions . So it was wise to declare them as `static`. `static` methods can be invoked by directly using the classname , hence no use of instantiating the class. They belong to the class, not specific objects of that class.

You can refer the [JLS 8.4.3.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.2) :

> A class method is always invoked without reference to a particular object.

Comment: @jlordo It *does* if it's the only one.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Thanks for letting me know. You're right. That's what I learned new today - although it makes sense in retrospect.

Comment: what do  u mean by " since it is the only constructor."

Comment: @user2088260 He means all the class's constructors are private.

Comment: Thank u sir for such detailed explanation ...!

Answer (score 2):

The Math class have all methods as a static, and you need to get the method from the class itself. `No need to create instance variable to access Static variable and methods`

Refer [Math Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) java doc. you find all method here static i,e. [Math.round](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round%28float%29)

Answer (score 1):

Private constructors means that they can only be called upon from within the class to which they belong, a good example of the use of private constructors can be found here [Can a constructor in Java be private?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816123/can-a-constructor-in-java-be-private)

Private constructors do however have nothing to do with the fact that you can use methods from the MATH class without instantiating them. This is because the methods of MATH class are static i.e. a static method can be called upon without instantiating an object of the class to which the methods belong.

As said in the comments above, you have no use of instantiating a MATH object, therefore the constructor is private, but you could use the MATH methods anyway had the constructor been public.